# How to compare if combobox item is equal with listview item or listview already contains combobox item in c#

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

How to compare or check whether the item in combobox is already existing in listview? Please help....

```
if (lvCart.Items.ContainsKey(cmbdummy.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Entry!");
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If you're holding same type item collections in both controls, use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedItem.ToString()` I guess.

Comment: Sir, it says it cannot convert object to string if I use SelectedItem...

Comment: Have you tried with cmbdummy.Text? 
if (lvCart.Items.ContainsKey(cmbdummy.text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Entry!");
        }

Comment: Yes I have tried. It doesn't work...

Comment: @bluffer: compare with `SelectedValue`, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with respective `SelectedValue`.

Try This:

```
if (lvCart.Items.ContainsKey(cmbdummy.SelectedValue.ToString()))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Entry!");
    }
```

Comment: It says cannot convert from object to string.

Comment: It says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Then it means your object is not initialized.